Can I go below recommended voltage range for a particular IC input pin?
The ISL71840SEH analog mux has an input pin VREF, which the datasheet says the recommended range is 4.5 to 5.5 V:

It goes on to say that the logic threshold is about 30% of VREF, so for 5V VREF the logic threshold would be about 1.5V.
Let's say I used 3.3V instead of 5V, then the logic threshold would be about 1V. If a 1V logic threshold is fine for me, then could I use 3.3V for VREF instead of the recommended 4.5V minimum? Or are there other consequences of going outside the recommended range?

The data sheet is quite clear: -
The VREF pin sets the logic threshold for the ISL71840SEH. The range 
for VREF is between 4.5V and 5.5V with a nominal voltage of 5V.

This means that you would need to contact the supplier if you wanted to set the Vref pin to +3.3 volts and, they will likely say that it needs to be nominally 5 volts.

You can because the data sheet does not forbid you to so. There is no mention what happens if you do go outside the recommended range, only the manufacturer knows that, which means you should ask the manufacturer for support.
However, using e.g 3.3V will be outside of the recommended range, which is of course, not recommended, and against the recommendation, so in a good design you would not do that.
